# How to prevent truncated output lines in Console2?

Tags: windows-7, console2

I just started using [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and can't seem to find a way to scroll horizontally when command output is wider than the current size of the window and when I try to resize the window the truncated information is just lost.

Is there a way to add horizontal scrolling or to fix the resizing issue? If not, are there programs similar to Console2 that do not have this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: Actually, my bad, no information is getting lost, it's just not resizing it properly.

EDIT: Turns out that if you resize Console2 to make it smaller and cutoff text you can't resize it and get it back?? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question might generate more attention on the [official forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/forums/forum/143117).